# JS matchMedia: Can you match the screen as well with this?

Tags: javascript

I have a two column layout where my footer copyright is on the left side. When I decrease the screen size to mobile for testing, the footer on the left, is put to the middle and the second column starts after the footer.

I can fix this with JavaScript with matchMedia(). However, matchMedia() only works on mobile. Is there a way to match media and screen? Something like matchMediaScreen()? See example:

```css
.branding-color { 
     background-color: darkblue;
}

.welcome,
.students { 
     color: white;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row vh-100">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <section class="row logo-area mb-5 p-3">
        <div class="col-6">
          <a href="/index.php">
            <img class="img-fluid" :src="logo" alt="Secret Logo" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-right">
          <img class="img-fluid " :src="hpoLogo" alt="Secret Logo">
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- row logo-area -->

      <div class="col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-center flex-column text-center uni-center">
        <div class="mb-5">
          <img class="img-fluid uni-logo" :src="universityLogo" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="login mb-5">
          <a class="btn btn-blue mr-2" href="/login.php">Login</a>
          <a class="btn btn-green" href="/register.php">Register</a>
        </div>
        <nav class="nav flex-column mb-5">
          <a href="#">Support</a>
          <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
          <a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
        </nav>
        <div class="social">
          <a href="#"><img :src="facebook" alt="" /></a>
          <a href="#"><img :src="twitter" alt="" /></a>
          <a href="#"><img :src="instagram" alt="" /></a>
          <a href="#"><img :src="mail" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer>
        <p class="text-center">© 2019 All rights reserved. Designed and hosted by Someone Special</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
    <!-- col-md-3 -->
    <div class="col-md-8 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center branding-color">
      <div class="col-md-8 welcome-white rounded">
        <h2 class="welcome m-0 font-weight-bold">Welcome</h2>
        <h2 class="students mb-5">Students</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- col-md-8 -->
    <div class="m-footer"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- row  -->
</div>
<!-- container-fluid -->
```

Comment: "However, matchMedia() only works on mobile" Are you sure? Can you take a look to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=matchMedia) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)?

Answer (score 0):

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries):

> In JavaScript, you can use the Window.matchMedia() method to test the window against a media query.

So, for example:

```
const query = window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 992px)");
```

What you insert is just a string, so you can do some smart things pretty easily with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) if you are using ES2015:

```js
const min = 576;
const getMediaQuery = minWidth =>
  window.matchMedia(`screen and (min-width: ${minWidth}px)`);
const query = getMediaQuery(min);

const screenTest = e =>
  e.matches
    ? console.info(`The window is at least ${min}px wide.`)
    : console.info(`The window is less than ${min}px wide.`);

query.addListener(screenTest);
screenTest(query);
```